# Google is not opened in browsers

Tags: windows-xp, google-chrome, browser, google-search

I have the following browsers installed on my system.

- Google Chrome, Version 33.0.1750.154 m
- Mozilla FireFox, Version 27.0.1
- Internet Explorer 8

Except for other sites, Google doesn't open in **all** of these browsers. When the link `http://www.google.com/` is entered in the address bar, it opens up the page as shown in the following:

[image: snap shot].

It happened suddenly a few days ago. Why does this happen? How do I fix it?

Comment: What extensions do you have installed on Chrome?

Comment: The first step is delete the Chrome profile and relaunch Chrome.

Comment: There is only Object Browser which is enabled on Chrome, @DanielChateau

Comment: Check your `hosts` file. Someone might be pulling a prank on you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds system based. You likely have poorly written spyware. See [this SuperUser article](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-do-i-get-rid-of-malicious-spyware-malware-viruses-or-rootkits-from-my-pc/100370#100370) for recommendations

Your host file may be modified:
 Check your host file:

1. Press <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
2. Type: %systemroot%\System32\drivers\etc press ok (you may need to tell it to show system files)
3. Double click on hosts and open with Notepad
4. The only line that should not have a # before it should be `127.0.0.1  localhost` (if this is a work computer, check with your IT staff before modifying this file).
5. Erase anything that is not that and save.

If you are behind a admin controlled network you may not be getting a good address for Google.

1. Press <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
2. Type cmd press ok.
3. In the black command window type: nslookup google.com
4. it should look something like the following (not exactly the same numbers though)

   `Name:    google.com
   Addresses:  2607:f8b0:4009:804::1006
             173.194.46.36
             173.194.46.37
             173.194.46.46
             173.194.46.34
             173.194.46.38
             173.194.46.35
             173.194.46.33
             173.194.46.32
             173.194.46.41
             173.194.46.40
             173.194.46.39`

**Edit due to comment:**
You certainly have malware. Your DNS is hijacked.
Follow the recommendations in the article I've linked above, I recommend [Malwarebytes Free](https://www.malwarebytes.org/). 
You may need to free your DNS see [this Microsoft article](http://support.microsoft.com/KB/305553) to check your DNS. You want it set to automatically obtain. If it is already set to automatically obtain, you may find it difficult to download anti-malware programs, in which case you should obtain them from another computer and portable media(thumb drive probably).

Comment: There is a `tmphosts` file in `C:\WINDOWS\System32\drivers\etc`. There is no `#` before `127.0.0.1       localhost`. Do you want to see the entire file?

Comment: Entering `nslookup google.com` on command line shows this, `Server:  du-113-122.sv-en.ru
Address:  46.19.113.122

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    google.com
Address:  46.202.194.197
`

Comment: You Have malware. See Step one. Delete any host file and tmphost file you have in there. I'm also adding to my answer based on your comment.

Comment: Also, your host file may be hidden. You may need to show hidden files to see it.

Comment: That's some useless malware though.

Comment: @user1167442 Hence why I called it poorly written :)

Comment: I have used Malwarebytes Free to scan the system. Removed objects that were listed by the tool still sometimes Google is not opened (usually it opens). It seems to me that I will have to reinstall the operating system. Are these malwares harmful to the system like viruses? (I have many applications running on the system using different servers and all of them require reconfigurations, if the OS is reinstall. It could be a time waste activity).

Comment: A virus is a type of malware. When I say malware I mean anything bad for your computer: Viruses, Spyware, Worms, rootkits etc. I would recommend an OS reinstall from the sound of it.