# Can't access any Google related Web pages or products

Tags: browser, gmail, internet-connection

A few hours ago something weird happened. I tried accessing my Gmail and it just kept loading.

So then I tried to go to a different website and it worked fine. Every single website works except Google. I cannot access my Google drive on my browser or on the Windows app. The same thing happens with every device accessing the Internet through our adsl. So its not my browser or my pc.

I can access Google from my mobile network just fine. If I tether my mobile network to my pc with my phone everything works great. Literally everything associated with Google is not working with my adsl.

Does anybody have any idea as to what the problem might be? I literally have no idea what is going on.

Comment: If you change your DNS servers can you connect?

Comment: Where should I change it?

Comment: There is plenty of documentation that explains how to change your DNS servers.

Comment: Should I change it on my router or pc?? I'm a networking noob. Sorry

Comment: Does not really matter.  Doing either would accomplish the end goal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google is not opened in browsers](http://superuser.com/questions/730568/google-is-not-opened-in-browsers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To user [Ramhound](https://superuser.com/users/83283/ramhound)'s point, the issue sounds a lot like a faulty DNS lookup.

1. Open a command prompt.
2. While connected to the DSL, run the command "nslookup google.com" and see if it resolves to an IP address. There should be numerous responses.

If there are no responses, then the true resolution lies with your ISP's DNS. The workaround is as such:

1. Open your network control panel. This can be achieved easily by doing: Start> Run> ncpa.cpl
2. Right-click your active network adapter. This will be the one that has text in or near the icon stating "Connected"
3. Find the item listed as "TCP/IP v4", click it, and click the "properties" button
4. Set a manual DNS entry of 8.8.8.8, or 4.2.2.1.
5. Save and/or click OK through the various menus, and attempt to connect to google.com again

If this workaround allows access, then you have confirmed the issue lies with the automated DNS you are receiving from your ISP or modem/router. Check your modem/router, and call your ISP.