# .google domain name redirects to localhost

Tags: linux, domain, google-search

The title says it all . Just try to visit `anything.google` and see if it redirects you to `127.0.0.1` or `localhost`.

Does this work for me alone or what because I just installed an apache2 server on my Lubuntu?

And if it doesn't can you find any information about this domain name, I just accidentally discovered it.

**EDIT:** output of nslookup as requested :

> m.google
> Server:       127.0.1.1
> Address:  127.0.1.1#53
>
> Non-authoritative answer:
> Name: m.google
> Address: 127.0.53.53

Comment: If you have `dig`, `nslookup` or `host` installed, please try looking up the domain name this way and update your question to include the output of the command.

Comment: host gives me :
m.google has address 127.0.53.53  
m.google mail is handled by 10 your-dns-needs-immediate-attention.google.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google is not opened in browsers](http://superuser.com/questions/730568/google-is-not-opened-in-browsers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This response is a special service from ICANN. [It’s about namespace collisions](https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/name-collision-2013-12-06-en) between internal networks and the internet.

Why this particular warning comes up for `.google`, I don’t know. As far as I know, a `.google` TLD has not been announced, yet it is listed in [the list of known TLDs](http://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt). Of course, if it’s an active TLD, you’ll simply get a `NXDOMAIN`, domain not found.

So yes, this also happens for me and probably just about everyone else.